# How does one prevent duplicate email addresses while users modify their email addresses after registration using the default MVC Membership Provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using the default ASP.NET MVC Membership Provider and I would like to allow user's to modify their email after they have created their account.  I do not want users to be able to use a duplicate email.

How do I allow a user to modify their email and check that the email is not in use elsewhere in the database?  I am not sure of the best way to do this type of check when using the default Membership Provider.

note - I know the Membership Provider itself performs this check when a user attempts to register their email address, I do not know how to perform this check at a later time (due to noobness).

note 2 - I only know of this method of accessing the user's email, is this the proper way to be accessing it?

```
MembershipUser useremail = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
ViewBag.Email = useremail.Email;
```

Comment: regarding note 2: yes, that is the correct method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can search for an existing username by that email:

```
String userName = MembershipProvider.GetUserNameByEmail(email)
```

If no match is found, `userName` will be null.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getusernamebyemail.aspx) for more info on this.

Also, if your MembershipProvider has `RequiresUniqueEmail = true` then this check should already be performed for you - as per [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.requiresuniqueemail.aspx) page.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  I do have RequiresUniqueEmail set to be true, but would that affect what happens when I build my own function to allow users to modify their email?